# Laravel auto DI is not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm attempting to create a repository and have it auto injected into some of my controllers.  I am using Laravel 4.1 and PHP 5.3.10

I get the error message `Class ConsumerRepositoryInterface does not exist`

I've setup a service provider like so...

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ConsumerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('ConsumerRepositoryInterface', function()
        {
            return new EloquentConsumerRepository(new Consumer);
        });
    }

}
```

I'm trying to inject it into my controller like so.

```
private $consumer;

public function __construct(ConsumerRepositoryInterface $consumer)
{
    $this->consumer = $consumer;
}
```

I've got the service provider registered in the providers array in `config\app.php` as `ConsumerServiceProvider`.  I've added `app/providers` and `app/repositories` where I have the service provider and repository respectively to the autoload classmap section of the `composer.json` file and have ran `composer dump-autoload`.

The confusing part is setting up my controller like so works fine...

```
private $consumer;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->consumer = App::make('ConsumerRepositoryInterface');
}
```

This tells me the service provider and repositories are all fine, Laravel is for some reason not able to automatically inject my dependency into the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was painfully obvious.

It was saying `ConsumerRepositoryInterface` did not exist because it didn't exist.  As soon as I made an actual interface and setup the EloquentConsumerRepository to implement it, everything worked.